# How to calculate BIC from Gaussian Process Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I'm currently using `scikit-learn` to fit a Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) to some 2-dimensional data. I want to compare this to another model using the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) through:

`BIC = k ln(n) - 2ln(L)`

but here k is the number of parameters estimated by the model, and is what I can't figure out. It's unclear to me what I should use here -- is this just 1 (the scale length), the number of points being fitted, or something else? Any help would be much appreciated, I'm sure this has an extremely simple answer!